# WildCard Find Replace CP

Tags: find, wildcards, pattern-matching

I'm trying to replace files that match a particular pattern* on CentOS, but it is not working.

I initially wrote:

```
cp example.com/(*)/orm-mysql/build/conf/(*)-conf.live.php example_dev.com/$1/orm-mysql/build/conf/$1-conf.live.php
```

I want to replace the files in the `example_dev.com` directory with the files of the same name in `example.com`.

*The pattern is `example.com/` then anything until `/orm-mysql/build/conf/` then a file prefixed with the first wildcarded value and ending in `-conf.live.php`.

I tried using `find` with `exec`:

```
find /var/www/html/example.com -name '*/orm-mysql/build/conf/*-conf.live.php' -exec echo {} \;
```

but it threw an error:

> find: warning: Unix filenames usually don't contain slashes (though pathnames do).  That means that '-name ‘*/orm-mysql/build/conf/*-conf.live.php’' will probably evaluate to false all the time on this system.  You might find the '-wholename' test more useful, or perhaps '-samefile'.  Alternatively, if you are using GNU grep, you could use 'find ... -print0 | grep -FzZ ‘*/orm-mysql/build/conf/*-conf.live.php’'

Which I think is because `-name` is for a file, not a path.

How can I accomplish this, is there an easier way than writing a shell script?

Some examples:

```
/var/www/html/example.com/video/orm-mysql/build/conf/video-conf.live.php
/var/www/html/example.com/images/orm-mysql/build/conf/images-conf.live.php
/var/www/html/example.com/audio/orm-mysql/build/conf/audio-conf.live.php
```

and they would replace:

```
/var/www/html/example_dev.com/video/orm-mysql/build/conf/video-conf.live.php
/var/www/html/example_dev.com/images/orm-mysql/build/conf/images-conf.live.php
/var/www/html/example_dev.com/audio/orm-mysql/build/conf/audio-conf.live.php
```

Comment: Did you try the suggestions from the error message? Also, why are you using parentheses around the `*`? That wouldn't really work anyway. Could you give us some example file names? I assume that the `$1` you are using, although not recognized by cp/shell, means that the file name also has the directory name in it, is that correct?

Comment: I tried the `wholename` and `samefile` but got the same error. I'm not sure what I'm suppose to put in place of the `...` in their example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would actually do this with a shell loop:

```
for dir in example.com/*; do
    prefix=${dir##*/}
    cp "$dir"/orm-mysql/build/conf/"$prefix"-conf.live.php \
        example_dev.com/"$prefix"/orm-mysql/build/conf/$1-conf.live.php
done
```

That will complain if the target directory doesn't exist, but will work as expected if it does. If you want to avoid the complaints, use this:

```
for dir in example.com/*; do
    prefix=${dir##*/}
    target=example_dev.com/"$prefix"/orm-mysql/build/conf/
    if [ -d "$target" ]; then
        cp "$dir"/orm-mysql/build/conf/"$prefix"-conf.live.php "$target"
    fi
done
```

Comment: When I run `echo $prefix` I don't get anything back but `echo $dir` gives me back the full path. I didn't try it with the `cp` yet, is it not accessible via `echo` (and if not is there some way to see the command prior to running it)?

Comment: @user3783243 ah sorry, my bad. See updated answer. The echo should work now.

Comment: Thanks, that works. What does the `${dir##*/}` do, or what is the phrasing for that so I can read more about it?

Comment: @user3783243 see "Substring Removal" here: http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html